# How to get VCS root ID in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I make a script for making some rest request.
But my VCS root ID in teamcity is diferent by the projet.

I found nothing for getting the VCS root ID in teamcity like %vcsroot.id% ...

[image: VCS Root id in yellow]

Comment: In TeamCity build there could be several VCS Roots attached to the build configuration. So you really need to know VCS Root ID in advance.

Also take a look [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-VCSProperties)

Comment: Thank's for answer but the VCS root id not accessible.

"vcsroot.<VCS root ID>.<VCS root property name>"
the <VCS root ID> is dynamical ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not best idea, but you can try something like this:

```
curl -u admin:password -X GET http://localhost:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/TestProject1
```

And then parse response to find VCS_ID.

Step by step:

1. I created some temporary project on my TC with id `TempProject`
2. Go to this url http://localhost/teamCity/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/TempProject (you need to change localhost to your working TC address and `TempProject` to your project id)
3. XML response contain `<vcsRoots ... />` tag with next param `href="/httpAuth/app/rest/vcs-roots?locator=project:(id:TempProject)"`
4. Then go to the http://localhost/teamCity/httpAuth/app/rest/vcs-roots?locator=project:(id:TempProject)
5. You will receive `<vcs-roots count="1">
   <vcs-root id="TempProjectVcsRootID" name="TempProjectVcs" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/vcs-roots/id:TempProjectVcsRootID"/>
   </vcs-roots>`
6. `TempProjectVcsRootID` it is vcs root id for TempProject

Comment: I have checked. It is working in my situation. Please double check.